# Hats are really small

Tags: bug, status-norepro, winter-bash-2014

Like, really, really, really small.

[image]

No option to resize. Changing hats does not change the size, unfortunately all other hats become just as small.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Switch to a different hat and then switch back.

Comment: @Servy lemme just pull up a screenshot, one moment

Comment: What browser? What OS? Are you zoomed in? Any add-ons or extensions?

Comment: chrome, no addons, no extensions, zoom is at %, win7

Comment: This is on your avatar or others? Or both?

Comment: All avatars of mines.

Comment: All hats share the same sizing settings. It is possible to shrink a hat if you move it to the side of the avatar and save (it is shrunk automatically). To expand it, simply open the control and resize it larger.

Comment: And the resizing controls don't work? Can you detail how they are not working?

Comment: From your nice and big warewolf hunter hat, looks like all is well now?

Comment: Well, the "show controls" checkbox can be missed, that's probably the case here, @Oded. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard completely missed that option until someone  pointed it out in the comments. quite fun resizing my hat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Click on `[ ]` show controls in "Your Hats" section. Locate the brown control, and resize your hats. The further the brown control is from your hat area, the larger the hat will get. All hats share the same sizing settings.

Comment: +1 for Paint freestyle.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, upvoted as well.